# How to write something in between "[ ]"

Tags: formatting

I want to produce the following output:[image]

I tried it by usind \Bigl[ and \Bigr] and the \shortstack command to stack the text on the right, but the the right ] is not on the correct height. Do you have any idea how to produce such a layout?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of just posting a drawing, edit your question to include a compilable document that shows what you did. Then people can help you more easily without having to guess what you've done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\left[`...`\right]` inside a regular equation (`\[`...`\]` or `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`) to allow the brackets to expands as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left[
  \quad % Left gap
  \mbox{SoMeTHiNG}
  \qquad
  \int F\,\mathrm{d}r
  \qquad
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
    The text next to the formula \\
        is written like this
  \end{tabular}
  \quad % Right gap
  \right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\biggl[\quad \textup{f.e.} \quad \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} \qquad 
\begin{matrix} \textup{The text next to the formula} \\
        \textup{is written like this}\end{matrix}\quad\biggr]\]
\end{document}
```